# Android Volley request listeners not firing

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to send a request to a server to retreive a simple json object using Volley, however the responses are never received and so my application bombs out after this due to the data not being there.

What im most confused about is the fact that there isnt even any errors coming through theres just nothing from volley at all.

My method to send the requests:

```
public void loadRemotePuzzles() {
    final String puzzleIndexURL = "https://www.goparker.com/600096/jumble/index.json";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, puzzleIndexURL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    ParsePuzzleHeaders(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("DEBUG", "Volley error: " + error.getMessage());
                    String errorResponse = "oops";
                }
            });
    Log.i("DEBUG", "Adding to queue");
    VRequestQueue.getInstance(mAppContext).addToQueue(request);
    Log.i("DEBUG", "Added to queue");
}
```

Comment: Try using `addToRequestQueue ` instead `addToQueue `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might see this thread and be in a similar position to me, my issue was that i was blocking the UI thread elsewhere which was stopping the Volley listeners firing, once i removed this the requests worked perfectly.